# Using _ViewStart on areas for nested content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a _ViewStart defining the master layout for my project (header, footer).

In this project, I have several Areas. Every area has the same header and footer, plus its own side menu. For that, I created a _ViewStart on the root dir of that area. Here is the (simplified) code:

/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

```
    <html>
        <div>
            //header
        </div>
        <div>
            @RenderBody
        </div>
    </html>
```

Area Foo -> /Areas/Foo/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="row">
<div class="sidemenu">
    //default sidemenu for this area
</div>
<div>
        @RenderBody()
</div>
</div>
```

The page /Areas/Foo/Views/Bar/Index.cshtml won't render and I get this error:

**CS0103: The name 'RenderBody' does not exist in the current context**

How to achieve this kind of master page nesting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but here it goes:

You can't reference the site's root _ViewStart directly on the _ViewStart of your area if you want a RenderBody there.

So the solution is:

**/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml** references **/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml**

**/Areas/Foo/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml** references **/Areas/Foo/Views/Shared/_AreaLayout.cshtml**

**/Areas/Foo/Views/Shared/_AreaLayout.cshtml** references **/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml**

And that's it. You have to use the "Shared" folder to have the method "RenderBody()" available.